# Array conversion gives string instead of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to convert two arrays into another array format.

Here is my code:

```js
var array1 = [ "Kolkata", "Begumpet", "Bellary"];

var array2 = [[[20,"Kolkata1"],[10,"Kolkata2c"]],
              [[0,"Begumpet1"],[10, "Begumpet2e"]],
              [[30, "Bellary1"],[0, "Bellary2a"]]]

console.log(array2);
var resultvalue = [];
for (i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    var result = "";
    var m = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < array2[i].length; j++) {
        if(m==0){
            result += "label: '" + array1[i] + "',";
            m++;
        }
        result += " '" + array2[i][j][1] + "': " + array2[i][j][0] + ", ";
    }
    resultvalue.push(result);
}
console.log(resultvalue);
```

It's producing what I want, except that the result is a string, while I need the actual array.

The expected output object should be like this:

```
dataset = [
    {label:"Kolkata", "Kolkata1":20, "Kolkata2c":10},
    {label:"Begumpet", "Begumpet1":0, "Begumpet2e":10},
    {label:"Bellary", "Bellary1":30, "Bellary2a":0},
];
```

Comment: Where did KOTAK come from? Isn't it suppose to be Kolkata in output you desire?

Comment: Sorry Tirthraj Barot. that is "Kolkata". by mistake i gave like that

Comment: Moreover according to me, any values like  "Kotak":25 must be an object within an object... So according to what I felt to be valid, I m putting my code below.

Comment: Alright @G Boomanikandan, I have added my answer..!

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with JSON, which is a text format. This is about converting one set of arrays to another array of objects. JSON is not involved.

Comment: ohhh thank you @trincot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate `array2` and map a new object for each entry.

```js
var array1 = ["Kolkata", "Begumpet", "Bellary"],
    array2 = [[[20, "Kolkata1"], [10, "Kolkata2c"]], [[0, "Begumpet1"], [10, "Begumpet2e"]], [[30, "Bellary1"], [0, "Bellary2a"]]],
    dataset = array2.map(function (a, i) {
        var o = { label: array1[i] };
        a.forEach(function (b) {
            o[b[1]] = b[0];
        });
        return o;
    });

console.log(dataset);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `Array.prototype.reduce` and `forEach` on the inner arrays to get the required array - demo below:

```js
var array1 = [ "Kolkata", "Begumpet", "Bellary"];
var array2 = [[[20,"Kolkata1"],[10,"Kolkata2c"]],[[0,"Begumpet1"],[10, "Begumpet2e"]],[[30, "Bellary1"],[0, "Bellary2a"]]];

var result = array2.reduce(function(p,c,i){
  var elem = {label : array1[i]};
  c.forEach(e => elem[e[1]] = e[0]);
  p.push(elem);
  return p;
},[]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with this ES6 code:

```js
var array1 = [ "Kolkata", "Begumpet", "Bellary"];
var array2 = [[[20,"Kolkata1"],[10,"Kolkata2c"]],
              [[0,"Begumpet1"],[10, "Begumpet2e"]],[[30, "Bellary1"],[0, "Bellary2a"]]]

var result = array2.map( (pairs, i) => 
    Object.assign ({ label: array1[i] }, ...pairs.map ( ([v, k]) => ({ [k]: v }))));
 
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you @trincot

Comment: You're welcome. Please note that you can only accept one answer (it seems you are trying to accept more than one).

Comment: hi trincot. i can agree but every response is correct that why i confused. but i learn More. every guys way of thinking is different. so i agree all response. thank you guys. thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

There were some corrections in your desired output JSON object according to the best practices of structure of JSON. So According to what I felt to be valid, here is the correct code.

Moreover I have used JSON.stringify() to print the JSON object.

And I also have modified the way you were building the output JSON object.

```js
var array1 = ["Kolkata", "Begumpet", "Bellary"];

var array2 = [
  [
    [20, "Kolkata1"],
    [10, "Kolkata2c"]
  ],
  [
    [0, "Begumpet1"],
    [10, "Begumpet2e"]
  ],
  [
    [30, "Bellary1"],
    [0, "Bellary2a"]
  ]
];

var resultvalue = [];
for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  var result = {};
  var temp = {};
  temp.label = array1[i];
  for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
    temp[[array2[i][j][1]]] = array2[i][j][0];
  }
  resultvalue.push(temp);
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(resultvalue));
console.log(resultvalue);
```

SORRY.... COULDN'T UNDERSTAND THE QUESTION... I UPDATED THE CODE.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a javascript object to JSON you have to call the `JSON.stringify` method.

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(array2);
```

Comment: You don't seem to have read beyond the question title. The OP is actually asking how to transform the data into an array of objects.

Comment: hi Cubi, i want to convert string to JSON but i dont want json to string to conversion